Pin Email workaround in Classic outlook without disabling conversation groups?
I want to emulate New Outlook email pinning. In Old Outlook, I added a category !Pinned and sorted Z->A and it brings that category to the top and keeps the emails in date order.
However it does not allow me to use conversation view (where email chains are grouped into a single entry). Is there any advanced view setting combo that works, or VBA custom rule or anything? My only idea is to have a second folder for the pinned category with a custom rule but that's not what I really want.

Do you mean the setting in Classic Outlook as shown in the below image?

And do you want the same view filter options in New Outlook?
If so, as i kwon, we can select the options in New Outlook:

If not, please provide more information for our better research.

Yes that's exactly what I've done so far. It just splits the conversations into individual emails

I'm afraid that grouping by conversation and grouping by category can't coexist.

Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Well I suppose when I asked the question I already knew the method I tried didn't work.. but I'm after a workaround, some clever idea that gets me 80% of the way there
